# Cobol not numeric name

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I am having some trouble with some cobol code. In the following code bellow it causes these two errors. The compiler does not like when I try and do the addition.

> ```
> CH7PPB.CBL:158: Error: 'NEW-DUES' is not numeric name
> CH7PPB.CBL:161: Error: 'NEW-INSURANCE' is not numeric name
> ```

```
   MOVE UNION-DUES TO OLD-DUES
   MULTIPLY UNION-DUES BY .04 GIVING NEW-DUES
   ADD UNION-DUES TO NEW-DUES
   MOVE INSURANCE TO OLD-INSURANCE
   MULTIPLY INSURANCE BY .03 GIVING NEW-INSURANCE
   ADD INSURANCE TO NEW-INSURANCE
```

NEW-DUES and NEW-INSURANCE are defined as follows.

```
       05   NEW-DUES                       PIC Z9(4).99.
       05   NEW-INSURANCE                  PIC Z9(4).99.
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you already solved the issue.

Just for the record, you cannot use edited formats in computations. The character "Z" in the `PICTURE` string of both variables turns the variable to be not considered numeric by the compiler.

You indeed have to declare a full numeric variable (no formatting) and move its result value to the formatted variable after.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by useing two temp variables not sure if this is the way to do it but it worked.

```
           MOVE ANNUAL-SALARY TO OLD-SALARY
           MULTIPLY ANNUAL-SALARY BY .07 GIVING TEMP
           ADD ANNUAL-SALARY,TEMP TO TEMP2
           MOVE TEMP2 TO NEW-SALARY
           MOVE ZEROS TO TEMP, TEMP2
           MOVE UNION-DUES TO OLD-DUES
           MULTIPLY UNION-DUES BY .04 GIVING TEMP
           ADD UNION-DUES,TEMP TO TEMP2
           MOVE TEMP2 TO NEW-DUES
           MOVE ZEROS TO TEMP, TEMP2
           MOVE INSURANCE TO OLD-INSURANCE
           MULTIPLY INSURANCE BY .03 GIVING TEMP
           ADD INSURANCE,TEMP TO TEMP2
           MOVE TEMP2 TO NEW-INSURANCE
           MOVE ZEROS TO TEMP, TEMP2
```

Comment: I think this might be a good time for you to learn about the COMPUTE verb! The above might work but it is horrible coding! For example, you might want to try: `COMPUTE NEW-SALARY = ANNUAL-SALARY + (ANNUAL-SALARY * 0.07)` or `COMPUTE NEW-SALARY = 1.07 * ANNUAL-SALARY`

Comment: +1 to Neal, adding, this is money.  Be sure to read up on `ON SIZE ERROR` declarative statements as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the COMPUTE suggested by NealB:

```
       MOVE ANNUAL-SALARY TO OLD-SALARY
       MULTIPLY ANNUAL-SALARY BY 1.07 GIVING NEW-SALARY
       MOVE UNION-DUES TO OLD-DUES
       MULTIPLY UNION-DUES BY 1.04 GIVING NEW-DUES
       MOVE INSURANCE TO OLD-INSURANCE
       MULTIPLY INSURANCE BY 1.03 GIVING NEW-INSURANCE
```

The use of TEMP2 in the code shown is particularly bad. It firstly relies on its initial value (presumably a VALUE clause) and for the second time through relies upon the 'MOVE ZEROS TO TEMP, TEMP2' at the end of the block. That's a bad way to do it. The repeated initialisation of TEMP is pointless, as TEMP is always the "target" of a GIVING, so its value at the time of the MULTIPLY is irrelevant.